# Need validation in my form page which uses react-bootstrap controller

Tags: forms, validation, react-bootstrap

I'm doing a form page using react-bootsrap controllers.

```
 <Form>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
              <Form.Label><i class="fa fa-question" aria-hidden="true"></i> What's your pet name?</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="enter answer"
                required
                autoFocus
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
              <Form.Label><i class="fa fa-question" aria-hidden="true"></i> What's your Favourite sport?</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                required
                placeholder="enter answer"
                autoFocus
              />
            </Form.Group>
            </Form>
```

I add required. But no validation taking place in ui. Also I want mandatory field sign a star(*) for the fields. Can anyone help me to add direct validation in this form

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand well what you mean, but from what I read you want validation when the page is finished loading.

1, add state for handling validation

```
const [isInvalid, setIsInvalid] = useState(true)
```

2, add props isInvalid to form control, and add onChange for change the state false

```
 <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="enter answer"
          required
          autoFocus
          isInvalid={isInvalid}
          onChange={(e) => setIsInvalid(false)}
        />
```